# Error inflating class com google android youtube player YouTubePlayerView

Tags: android, json, layout, youtube-api, layout-inflater

**Hello, I'm tendando inflate a layout with YouTubePlayerView widget, however I come across the below error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.pedro.masterwc, PID: 770
                  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                      at com.example.pedro.masterwc.Adapters.VideoAdapter.getView(VideoAdapter.java:45)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
```

**What may be in error? Can someone help me ?
Below are my classes.**

ListaVideosTeste.java

```
class ListaVideosTeste extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

ArrayList<Videos> videosList;
VideoAdapter adapter;

public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDveKkSzopPSk7ck4ZDbR9YGBe4Mm35DYY";


private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rows);

    videosList = new ArrayList<Videos>();
    new ListaVideosTeste.JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://www.masterwebchef.com.br/wsmwc/teste/get_videos_channel4.php");


    //cria a lista e exibi os dados retornados do json
    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_v);
    adapter = new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.teste, videosList);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Houve um erro ao carregar o video!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                    boolean wasRestored) {

    youTubePlayer = player;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Video carregado com sucesso!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
    }
}


//faz a conexao com a URL do Json
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(ListaVideosTeste.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Por favor, aguarde...");
        dialog.setTitle("Conectando ao servidor");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    //Recebe os dados do Json
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("channel1");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Videos v = new Videos();

                    v.setTitle(object.getString("title"));
                    v.setDescription(object.getString("description"));
                    v.setLink_to_youtube(object.getString("youtube_embed"));
                    //v.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                    //v.setHeight(object.getString("height"));
                    //v.setSpouse(object.getString("spouse"));
                    //v.setChildren(object.getString("children"));
                    v.setImage(object.getString("image"));

                    videosList.add(v);
                }
                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Não foi possivel acessar o servidor...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

VideoAdapter.java

```
class VideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Videos> {

    ArrayList<Videos> videoslist;
    LayoutInflater vi;
    int Resource;
    ViewHolder holder;


    public VideoAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Videos> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Resource = resource;
        videoslist = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {

            //holder = new ViewHolder();
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.teste, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            holder.description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescriptionn);
            holder.youtube_embed = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDateOfBirth);

            YouTubePlayerView youtube = (YouTubePlayerView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            youtube.setTag(videoslist.get(position).getLink_to_youtube());
            youtube.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, (YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener) this);



            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(videoslist.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.description.setText(videoslist.get(position).getDescription());
        holder.youtube_embed.setText(videoslist.get(position).getLink_to_youtube());
        //holder.link_to_youtube.initialize(youtube.API_KEY, (YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener) VideoAdapter.this);


        return v;
    }

    public static final class ViewHolder extends Fragment {

        public static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyDveKkSzopPSk7ck4ZDbR9YGBe4Mm35DYY";

        public ImageView imageview;
        public TextView title;
        public TextView description;
        public TextView youtube_embed;


    }

}
```

Layout teste.xml